# Where is nuget.exe in the .net core docker SDK

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm using the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster` image to build a docker image, but I need to add the Telerick nuget feed source.  I can pass in a `nuget.config` file and it will work, so I know nuget itself is working when the `dotnet restore` operation runs.

Nuget must be in that image somewhere, but apparently not in the path.  So when I try to run this in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN nuget.exe sources add -Name telerik -Source https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget/ -username myusername -password mypassword
```

I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: nuget.exe: not found
```

Where is nuget.exe in the dotnet core docker image?

Comment: find . -name nuget.exe -type f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the nuget executable for dotnet core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408966/where-is-the-nuget-executable-for-dotnet-core)

Answer (score 0):

The `nuget` CLI itself is not included with the .NET Core SDK itself.

The .NET Core SDK includes a subset of `nuget` functionality as built-in. For other functionality, you have to fall back to workarounds.

[Telerik docs point out that you have to put your configuration in the `Nuget.config` file in .NET Core](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/first-steps-cli#integrating-ui-for-aspnet-core).